# Remove query in MongoDB in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mongodb, google-maps

I wanted to delete all of the documents from the tweets that I collected in Twitter Streaming API that doesn't have "coordinates.coordinates" to save space since they can't be used to map in Google Maps API. Basically, I wanted to delete them before the actual mapping starts in the code so I placed it first line in the body of the HTML. However I'm wondering why it doesn't delete the documents? Code runs without errors. It just doesn't delete the documents I wanted to be removed. Here's my code:

```
 <?php

  //this remove line doesn't work.
  $collection->remove(array(["coordinates.coordinates"=> ['$exists'=> false]]));

 ?>
```

However when I try to delete them in the mongoDB shell, it works using the same query `db.sample_collection.remove({"coordinates.coordinates": {$exists: false}});`

Comment: remove `array(`

Comment: Oh it works! Why doesn't it need the `array()`? I've looked into many examples already and all of them contain `array()` @AyushGupta

Comment: Because you're currently having an array in an array. `array([...])` is the same as `array(array(...))`. `[...]` is just a short version of defining one.

Comment: Cool! Thanks to the two of you AyushGupta and MagnusEriksson